# NSTextField Fades Out After Subclassing

Tags: swift, cocoa, subclass, nstextfield

I've subclassed an NSTextField with the following code:

```
import Cocoa

class CustomSearchField: NSTextField {
    override func draw(_ dirtyRect: NSRect) {
        self.wantsLayer = true
        let textFieldLayer = CALayer()
        self.layer = textFieldLayer
        self.backgroundColor = NSColor.white
        self.layer?.backgroundColor = CGColor.white
        self.layer?.borderColor = CGColor.white
        self.layer?.borderWidth = 0
        super.cell?.draw(withFrame: dirtyRect, in: self)
    }
}

class CustomSearchFieldCell: NSTextFieldCell {
    override func drawingRect(forBounds rect: NSRect) -> NSRect {
        let minimumHeight = self.cellSize(forBounds: rect).height
        let newRect = NSRect(x: rect.origin.x + 25, y: (rect.origin.y + (rect.height - minimumHeight) / 2) - 4, width: rect.size.width - 50, height: minimumHeight)

        return super.drawingRect(forBounds: newRect)
    }
}
```

This is all working fine and it draws my NSTextField just as I wanted. The only problem is, as soon as I make some other part of the interface the first responder (clicking outside the NSTextField), the text inside the NSTextField (placeholder or filled in text) is fading out. As soon as I click on it again, it fades back in. I've been searching for quiet a while now, but can't really figure out why this is happening. I just want the text to be visible all the time, instead of fading in and out.

It has to do with the CALayer that I'm adding to accomplish my styling.

Whenever I run the same settings from viewDidLoad on the textfield, it works like a charm. For example:

```
class ViewController: NSViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var searchField: NSTextField!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        initCustomSearchField()
    }

    private func initCustomSearchField() {
        searchField.wantsLayer = true
        let textFieldLayer = CALayer()
        searchField.layer = textFieldLayer
        searchField.backgroundColor = NSColor.white
        searchField.layer?.backgroundColor = CGColor.white
        searchField.layer?.borderColor = CGColor.white
        searchField.layer?.borderWidth = 0
        searchField.delegate = self
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't create and set properties at every draw, set them once or when they change. Don't call `super.cell?.draw`, call `super.draw`.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion! But that causes the placeholder to be upside down on first load and the fade in / fade out problem remains.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`draw` method should really be used to draw the view not setting the properties.And for your problem don't set to self.layer directly use `sublayer` instead .

My suggestion for your code:

```
class CustomTextField :NSTextField {

    override init(frame frameRect: NSRect) {
        super.init(frame: frameRect)

        setupView()
    }

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        setupView()
    }

    func setupView(){
        textColor = .green
    }
}

class CustomTextFieldCell: NSTextFieldCell {

    override init(textCell string: String) {
        super.init(textCell: string)
        setupView()
    }

    required init(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)

        setupView()
    }

    func setupView(){
        backgroundColor = .red
    }


    override func drawingRect(forBounds rect: NSRect) -> NSRect {
        let newRect = NSRect(x: (rect.width - rect.width/2)/2, y: 0, width: rect.width/2, height: 20)
        return super.drawingRect(forBounds:newRect)
    }

    override func draw(withFrame cellFrame: NSRect, in controlView: NSView) {
        super.draw(withFrame: cellFrame, in: controlView)
        controlView.layer?.borderColor = NSColor.white.cgColor
        controlView.layer?.borderWidth = 2
    }

}
```

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by the draw method should only be used to draw the view. When drawing the view you also set the properties right, or am I mistaken? Could you go a bit more in depth about that? Also when using a sublayer as you said above, the border still get's drawn and none of the properties is being executed on the NSTextField

Comment: you're setting lots of color properties of your textfield in draw method which is in my opinion not a good place to do.You can do all of them for example in the viewDidLoad with just a reference or even using didSet. Draw method is used to create custom Views that cannot be created with their own properties. I'm not sure if I understand the last part of your comment about properties, could you give me an example.

Comment: Hm, but once you would be using this textfield styling across different NSTextFields, wouldn't you need to run this code in every viewDidLoad every single time? A subclass would be more useful at that point right? So that was why I thought I could set color properties in the draw method. Regarding the last part of my previous comment, if I use the above code, my NSTextField still draws a border, although it shouldn't be doing that with the code above.

Comment: ok , in that case subclass your `NSTextField` and override the `init` methods  and set the color in them. When you set it in draw , every time the view changes draw method is called and you'r setting properties over and over again but if you set it in the initializer you set only one time. For the border part I think you're looking for `isBordered = false`

Comment: I'm also changing the insets of the textfield through NSTextFieldCell so if I would set `isBordered = false`, that breaks. Therefore I'm using borderWidth = 0. One last question regarding the override of the init. The override of NSTextField requires a frame `(override init(frame frameRect: NSRect))`, where do I set that to so I can return `super.init()?`. Sorry bit new to everything in Xcode and still learning!

Comment: I don't really know why the border behave that way but the only workaround that I can think of is using border with same color. I updated the Code . I hope it's helpful.

Comment: Thanks for your help, this did the trick. I'm not sure why I was having such a hard time with that init, because this was what I was thinking of as well. Perhaps I made a typo that was causing an error. Anyways, learned a lot today. I tweaked it a bit and everything is up and running.